# Can jest test a thenable?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-promise

As I understand it, `await`ing an object with a `then` method (*thenable*) just calls the `then` method. I cannot get this to work with jest:

```
test('test thenable', async () => {
  const thenable = {
    then: () => 1
  };
  const actual = await thenable;
  expect(actual).toEqual(1);
});
```

This throws a jest error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error

Is is possible to test a *thenable* object with async?

### Background

I'm trying to test an already configured knex querybuilder. The code I'm testing is this:

```
const query = db('my_table')
  .where('key', 'someValue')
  .select('key', 'value');
const results = await query;
```

The `db` variable is an already configured Knex object, identifying the client and configuration.

So, `db` is a function that return an object with `where` and `select` methods **and** it must have the `then` method so it can be `await`ed. At least that is how I understand how it works.

Comment: I'm surprised your `const query...` version doesn't work because you have a promise, right? You can go ahead and make your assertions after awaiting, and all should be well in terms of the test suite.

Comment: It does not work, same error. I've checked and the query does have a `then` method (e.g. query.then()). I've also checked and in my actual code, calling `query.then()` returns the db results (just like doing `await query`. The test provided is the simplest test that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, for example, we have a `findById` method in `SomeDaoImpl` class and use `knex` Query builder within the method. I use `IKnex` interface to emulate the real interface of `knex` query builder.

`index.ts`:

```js
interface IKnex {
  where(...args: any): any;
  raw(...args: any): any;
  select(...args: any): any;
  then(): any;
}

class SomeDaoImpl {
  private knex: IKnex;
  constructor({ knex }) {
    this.knex = knex;
  }
  public findById(id: string) {
    return this.knex.where({ id }).select();
  }
}

export { SomeDaoImpl, IKnex };
```

You can mock chained methods of `knex` Query builder like below:

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { SomeDaoImpl, IKnex } from './';

const knexMocked: jest.Mocked<IKnex> = {
  where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  raw: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  then: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
};

const someDaoImpl = new SomeDaoImpl({ knex: knexMocked });

describe('SomeDaoImpl', () => {
  it('t1', async () => {
    (knexMocked.where() as jest.Mocked<IKnex>).select.mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actualValue = await someDaoImpl.findById('1');
    expect(actualValue).toBe('mocked data');
    expect(knexMocked.where).toBeCalledWith({ id: '1' });
    expect(knexMocked.where().select).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57811289/index.spec.ts
  SomeDaoImpl
    ✓ t1 (12ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.033s
```

The completed demo is here: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57811289

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Jest` can test a *thenable* object with `async`.

The `then` function should accept a `success` callback, and optionally a `error` callback.

The way the code is currently written the `then` function doesn't accept any parameters and thus it never calls the `success` callback...so it never resolves and `await` continues waiting until the test times out.

To fix it just add a `success` parameter and call it with the resolved value:

```
test('test thenable', async () => {
  const thenable = {
    then: success => { success(1); }
  };
  const actual = await thenable;
  expect(actual).toEqual(1);  // Success!
});
```